# How to get APPLICATION_ENV in .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to get APPLICATION_ENV and other custom variables in .htaccess file?

$_SERVER:

```
[
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'xx.example.com'
    'HTTP_X_GATE_HOST' => 'xx.entrance.com'
    'APPLICATION_ENV' => 'development'
]
```

This works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xx.example.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index-dev.php [NC,L]
```

But:

```
RewriteCond %{APPLICATION_ENV} development
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index-dev.php [NC,L]
```

just won't work.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} development
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index-dev.php [NC,L]
```

This won't work neither... Please help :|

Comment: How and where are you setting `APPLICATION_ENV`?

Comment: @anubhava, SetEnv in httpd.conf :)

Comment: Do you have control on `httpd.conf` ?

Comment: @anubhava, yes, but I still have no idea about it, maybe it's impossible... I've chose another way to get my target. thanks a lot.

Comment: Answers are still welcomed~ :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
```

with this line:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

Env variable created by `SetEnvIf` are available for `mod_rewrite` to evaluate later, which is not the case with `SetEnv` due to sequencing of loading of Apache modules.

Comment: It works, thanks! and I also find nginx proxy_set_header variables can be accessed by `%{HTTP:XXX}` ! Haha